# typesetting: mixture of citation styles

Tags: citing, natbib, typography, cite-package, multiple-citations

I have a stylistic question regarding mixture of citation styles, rather than a technical one:

If I find let's say Einstein's field equations in a text book I, strictly speaking, have to cite that textbook if I want use exact the same form of those equations and Einstein as primary source.

In my case Einstein has written the Equations in a slightly different form than the modern one, i.e. I am not allowed to omit the secondary source/textbook. I find it very awkward to have let's say something like `(Einstein, 1916; author_xyz, 2016)`, as it might seem that I do not understand that the Equations were derived 100 years earlier by Einstein and that the textbook is only one of a hundred with those Equations in it.

Would it be awkward to cite the very originals in author-year style and secondary sources (e.g. a particular textbook out of many other ones containing the same information) in numerical mode?

I have something like this in mind: `(Einstein, 1916) [2]`. Would you consider this as a typesetting no-go, or as legit?

Comment: I would use numeric citation for both, but put Einstein additionally in verbose in your text. Something like `This is governed by Einstein's equation [1], which we can write as [2]: ...`

Comment: Things like Enstein's field equations or the Schrödinger equation are referred to as *common knowledge* and do not need a citation at all.